# Bitwise operation not concatenating with string in print() in Java

Tags: java, printing, bitwise-operators, operator-precedence

This code

```
int a = 6;
System.out.print("The result is " + a*a);
```

works just fine, but this one

```
int a = 6;
System.out.print("The result is " + a^a);
```

produces an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - Erroneous tree type:   at
>   pkg1.pkg4.taking.input.TakingInput.main(TakingInput.java:11)

Why so?

The question arose when I was trying to print the results of several bitwise operations in one swoop, like so:

```
System.out.print(a&b + "\n" + a|b + "\n" + a^b);
```

I looked up the description of the `print()` method and several topics on bitwise operators and printing to the console on SO including the recommended topics when composing the question, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I wonder what Java version are you compiling this with, it doesn't compile with [tag:java-11] for sure, forget `RuntimeException`!

Comment: That's what the error says: `uncompilable source code`. Another problem was I was using single quotes instead of double quotes with `\n`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because the `+` has higher [precedence](http://operator-precedence.com/java) than the `^` so it compiles to:

```
("The result is " + a) ^ a
```

Which obviously will not work. Put parenthesis around it:

```
System.out.print("The result is " + (a^a));
```

Or as Holger mentioned, you can eliminate this problem by using `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("The result is %d", a^a);
```

Comment: @JohnAllison If you used an IDE, you would probably know about this before you actually compile and run it.

Comment: @Jai The OP surely used an IDE as without, he wouldn’t even try to run a program which didn’t compile. Besides that, here, the original Java designers are to blame. Using `+` for string concatenation was a big mistake. It not only has an unfortunate precedence, the usual expectation of commutativity for an addition does not hold when at least one of the operands of `+` is a string. But even Java itself has an alternative, `System.out.printf("The result is %d", a^a);`…

Comment: @Holger Hmm, my Eclipse is showing a compile time error when I do this. I guess it's the same whichever way - you can always miss the error messages and run the application...

Comment: @Jai the standard `javac` command line tool does not generate `.class` files when there are compile errors, hence, it is impossible to run the application afterwards. It is a special (dubious imho) option of IDEs to still generate classes on compiler errors, which will throw an exception at runtime then. You can turn this feature off and never miss an error, but the default is on for most IDEs.